# How to start my personal Zoom room using Siri on macOS?

Tags: macos, siri, zoom.app, video-conference

I want to be able to say. . .

> Hey Siri, open my Zoom room

. . . and have it open my personal Zoom room on my Mac. How can I achieve this? macOS doesn’t yet have Siri Shortcuts.

Comment: What steps have you tried already to get this to work?

Comment: @fsb Figured it out! Tried hooking into Siri first, but realised an easier way was to just save a script as an application that Siri can launch. Posted as a self-answer for future wanderers.

Comment: I suppose this a specific instance of more general problem of “How do I create custom Siri voice commands on macOS?” To which the answer is “Save scripts as an application!” Should I edit the question to be more general, or keep it specific?

Answer (score 4):

### Solution: Use a script saved an application

Siri on macOS doesn’t support third-party integration yet, but it can launch applications—thus, we can save an AppleScript as an application and have Siri activate it.

### Steps

1. Open Script Editor.
2. Create a new document and type in the following:

   ```
   tell application "zoom.us" to activate

   tell application "System Events"
       tell process "zoom.us"

           set StartMeeting to menu item "Start Meeting" of menu "zoom.us" of menu bar 0

           repeat while not enabled of StartMeeting
               delay 0.25
           end repeat

           click StartMeeting

       end tell
   end tell
   ```

   The `repeat while not enabled` section makes the AppleScript wait until Zoom has finished launching before trying to open your Zoom room. Otherwise, it won’t work.
3. Save it, and in the save dialog, call the script “My Room Zoom”, save it to the `/Applications` folder, and set the file format to “Application”

   [image: Save Dialog]
4. Done!

Now you can say “Hey Siri, open my Zoom Room” and Siri will interpret your command as “launch the application called ‘My Room Room.’”

This application will launch Zoom if it isn’t already running and then start a meeting with your default settings.

Note that the first time you launch the application, it will ask for some permissions on Catalina, and you’ll have to go into System Preferences > Security and Privacy > Privacy > Accessibility and tick the box for “My Zoom Room.”

### Bonus: Create a global keyboard shortcut

1. Open Automator
2. Create a new document of type “Quick Action” (formerly called Services)
3. Drag in a “Run AppleScript” action and type in:

   ```
   on run
       tell application "My Zoom Room" to activate
   end run
   ```
4. Adjust the Quick Action image and colour if you want, and save it as “Open my Zoom Room.”

   It should look something like this:

   [image: Automator script]
5. Now open up System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts. Go to “Services” and scroll until you see “Open my Zoom room.” Click to set a shortcut. I use `Cmd-Ctrl-Opt-Z`.

Done!

You can now press `Cmd-Ctrl-Opt-Z` anytime anywhere to launch your personal Zoom room, regardless of whether Zoom was already running or not.